# Which is the best dataset for an anova; raw or blup values?

Tags: r, mixed-model, anova, lme4-nlme, repeated-measures

I have a set of 150 rice varieties, which have different environmental classifications. I have measured a trait, y, on four repeats of each variety.
I want to test the effect of environmental classification on the trait. Is it most appropriate for me to run an anova (trait y ~ environmental classification):
1.) using the blup value (extracted from a lm where y is a function of variety) for each variety or
2.) using the raw data, i.e. incorporating all four repeats of each variety instead of the blup value for each variety.

Answer (score 0):

You have repeated measures data, and you definitely should use the raw data directly! Maybe you could use a mixed models anova, the details of wich depends on detailed information about your data you did not yet tell us.

So please augment your post with more details about your experimental set-up.